# SSRS Export Pop-Up Warning

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssrs-2016

I'm building a new reporting server using SSRS 2016 and have been given one specification I'm not sure is even possible. My supervisor wants a pop-up message whenever someone exports a report that notifies them that any data is only valid up to the time of export and any exported reports will not be supported by IT.

I get what he's after and why but I can't find anything online about how to implement this or even if it's possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.